# To mix sounds using OpenAl

Tags: iphone, audio, openal, mixing

Anybody have any idea about how to mix sounds in iphone.We can use OpenAl that i know but need some sample application or code which would be easier for me to understand this concept As i have seen some apples demo application which uses openGl along with openAl and is too confusing for me to understand this as i am new to this openGl environment

Thanks All in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you visit here
http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Documentation/OpenAL_Programmers_Guide.pdf
and download the guide. There are plenty of code snippets in the guide that can help you build the code base that you need. Works on the iPhone too, I built a mixer once myself :) 
Good luck!

EDIT

http://www.devmaster.net/articles/openal-tutorials/lesson1.php

http://kcat.strangesoft.net/openal-tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks for the links but none of them are iphone tutorials some use C,C++And java but i need for iphone or ipad (objective c) the PDF book is helpful.

Comment: Hi! openal is not an iPhone specific api, it is plain c, the code provided in the tutorials works on the iPhone too.